# Два события в одном addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Написал скрипт, который при наведении курсора на серый блок подсвечивает картинку красным цветом.

Но у меня появилось чувство, **будто я криво написал код JS.**

Вследствие чего у меня возник закономерный вопрос: **Как объединить mouseover и mouseout в одну функцию addEventListener? То есть, чтобы 2 события были в одном addEventListener. Да и вообще, грамотно ли я написал JS код?**

```js
let block = document.querySelector('.second');
let img = document.querySelector('.icon');

block.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  img.style.opacity = '0';
});

block.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  img.style.opacity = '1';
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: orange;
}

.second {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.icon2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="second">

    <img class="icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/YQGCtCv/2311.png">
    <img class="icon2" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WMcYq1/233.png">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Не нужно объединять, это 2 разных event listener'а, все нормально. Вопрос только, почему не сделать этого средствами CSS?

Comment: В CSS нельзя сделать, чтобы при наведении на серый блок, стиль применялся к выборочному элементу внутри этого серого блока. Ну или я чего-то не понимаю =(

Comment: Почему же нельзя? `.block:hover > img {}` - или я чего-то не понимаю в вашем вопросе?

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример кода, если конечно вас это не затруднит =)

Comment: Конечно, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь, судя по всему, имеет место быть проблема XY. Вам не нужно использовать JavaScript для решения этой задачи вообще. Достаточно простого CSS.

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: orange;
}

.second {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* добавлено */

.second:hover>.icon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.icon2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="second">

    <img class="icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/YQGCtCv/2311.png">
    <img class="icon2" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WMcYq1/233.png">

  </div>

</div>
```

Но если отвечать на ваш конкретный вопрос

> Да и вообще, грамотно ли я написал JS код?

То да, вполне грамотно, 2 event listener'а в данной ситуации - вполне закономерно. Можно, конечно, обойтись одним, но код будет сложнее читать.

Comment: А как сделать один addEventListener для двух событий?

Comment: @Домик начал писать ответ и задумался, можно ли вообще. Не уверен, что можно. Да и не нужно вам это в любом случае.

Comment: @Домик думал просто добавить wrapper и проверять `event.target` у события `mouseover`. Но теперь не уверен, что оно так сработает. Не забивайте себе голову ерундой в общем :)

Comment: В моём случае может и не надо, но мне чисто любопытно, так как меня уже третьи сутки не покидает мысль о двух событиях в одном addEventListener. Это вообще реально реализовать? Или я брежу?

Comment: @Домик вообще - реально. И иногда в плане производительности это единственное нормально решение. Но конкретно в вашем случае - не уверен. Как реализовать? Представьте, что у вас на странице есть родительский блок, в котором 10000 `input`'ов. И ваш нужно слушать `focus` и `blur` на каждом из них. Вы можете навесить 10000 обработчиков на каждый из инпутов, а можете повесить один `click` на родителя и проверять `event.target`'ом, куда действительно кликнули. Но там уже возникает куча подводных камней в виде клавиатурной навигации и т.п. вещей.

Comment: В вашем случае, в теории, можно повесить один `mouseover` куда-нибудь на `body`. И проверять `event.target`: если равен элементу картинки - ставим один `opacity`, если нет - другой. Но не надо так делать.

Comment: Спасибо за все, а есть ли ссылки или статья о двух событиях в одном addEventListener?

Comment: Наверняка есть. Поищите. У меня лично в загашниках нет :)

Comment: За помощь, поставлю вам везде плюсики =)

Comment: И еще последний вопрос =)  Вы говорили, что у меня проблемы с XY. Что это и как это решить?

Comment: @Домик https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Забыл спросить, а если у меня 20-30 элементов, которые надо так анимировать. Писание по 20-30 раз каждый раз second:hover > .icon это не приведет ли к проблеме с оптимизацией/производительностью?

Comment: @Домик не должно.